# JPA - how to get auto generated id in constructor?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What I want to achieve to take auto generated ID, hash it and save it into other field in the class, but at the stage of creating object by constructor ID is not yet generated. Any workaround ideas?

````
@Entity
public class MyClass {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      Long id;
      
      String hashID;
      
      MyClass(){
         this.hashID = Utils.hashID(id);
      }
    //setters and getters
  
}
```
````

Comment: What is the purpose of this `hashID` property? It seems to be redundant to store the hash of an existing field. Perhaps you want to calculate it on the fly in a special _getter_ method?

Comment: I want to store hashed id, because I am using hashed Id as a some value in several places in my client app and it's will be easier to store hashed value than hashing id every time when I need this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way that I can think of is you can use an entity lifecycle callback event like `@PostLoad` which is called when the entity is loaded in the persistence context, and initialize your hashed field from the id.

E.g.

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     Long id;
      
     String hashID;
     
     @PostLoad
     public void postLoad() {
         // Here id is initialized
         this.hashID = Utils.hashID(id);
     }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly but do you know how much it will affect the performance of creating object?

Comment: I think that depends on what you do in the callback, if it doesn't do something performance intensive, then everything should be fine.